# Перенос сайта на хостинг Laravel

Tags: laravel

Перенес файлы сайта в директорию `public_html`, в файле `.env` заменил имя БД, имя пользователя и пароль, но при переходе на сайт выводится ошибка:

> SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

(root - имя пользователя на локалке). То есть *Laravel* как бы не замечает файл `.env`. Пробовал чистить кэш - не помогло. Есть идеи?

Comment: А версия Laravel какая?

Comment: Проверьте файл `/app/config/database.php`

Comment: @VenZell
Версия 5.4
В database данные же берутся из .env
 'mysql' => [
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            ...
        ],

Comment: Может все-таки пароль или логин просто неверны?

Comment: @Romchik так дело не в этом.Пароль и логин верны. Суть в том, что Laravel обращается к root и к БД с именем "имя_стараяБД", которой в принципе нет в проекте, потому что я заменил эти имена после того, как залил на хостинг.Получается они где-то есть в кэше, но я не могу его отчистить.

Answer (score 1):

Помогло: В `laravel_folder/bootstrap/cache` поменять имя `config.php` на любое другое. Собственно именно там хранятся старые данные о БД и прочее. 
Решение было найдено [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31455829/laravel-5-clear-cache-in-shared-hosting-server) .